# How do I suppress this COM Generics warning?

Tags: .net, vb.net, msbuild, compiler-warnings

I'm compiling a VB.Net 2.0 app (created in VS2008) using msbuild, and now I've added a generic return type, it's giving me the following:

> Warning: Type library exporter
>   encountered a generic type instance in
>   a signature. Generic code may not be
>   exported to COM.

Having just spent ages removing all of the previous warnings, I don't really want to add a new one.  Any idea how to get rid of it (aside from not using generics)?

I don't know what details I'd put in the  attribute, or what number to put in the project-level ignore list.

Comment: You should *not* be exporting open Generic types/methods to COM, it has no way of handling that.  You should only export *closed* Generic types/methods.

Comment: Sure - to be clear, I'm not trying to access this library with COM, it's a fully managed project, which is why I'm happy to hide this warning.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you have to expose that library to COM ?
If not, specify ComVisible(false)

Comment: That's done the trick!  Thanks.  I don't know why it's so hard to find info on suppressing compiler warnings.

Comment: You should not suppress compiler warnings.  You should fix the code, so that the warnings disappear. :)

Comment: Well, if removing the use of generics is fixing my code, I guess I could do!  Although I suppose setting ComVisible to False for code that isn't supposed to be visible to COM is also fixing it..

Comment: Where did I say you should change the code to not use Generics ?  I didn't say that.  I've said that the method that returns a generic type should not be exposed to COM since it is not usable in COM.

Comment: Syntax like:
<Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisible(False)> Public Class foo