# Does COM allow closed generic types?

Tags: c#, generics, dll, com, class-library

I have created a .Net class assembly that eventually may see distribution to external customers that may want to use it from non-.Net languages, such as C++.

To this end I am trying to make it COM compatible. This being my first foray with COM I could be on completely the wrong track!

So I fired up `tlbexp MyClassLibrary.dll` but it produces a bunch of warnings about generic types:

> TlbExp : warning TX8013117D : Type library exporter warning processing 'MyClassLibrary.IFoo.FooMethod(#0), MyClassLibrary'. Warning: Type library exporter encountered a generic type instance in a signature. Generic code may not be exported to COM.

Some are for nullable types (I have a plan to replace these with type-specific struct types maybe). The others are for occasions that I have used `IList<>`.

While looking for a good solution to this latter issue I stumbled on a comment by casperOne on this question: [How do I suppress this COM Generics warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4388433/1292918), that seems to indicate that while open generic types are not allowable in COM, closed generic types should be.

All occasions I have exposed `IList<>` usage I have specified the type, ie they are closed generics, such as in the following example code:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    IList<string> FooMethod(IList<string> bar);
}
```

If this is correct why does my closed generic type usage cause these warnings? Have I misunterstood closed-ness? Is casperOne's comment incorrect in this regard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Hans Passant posted an excellent answer but then deleted it, I'm not sure why. In it he mentioned that of course the attributes applied to a generic type do not change simply because the type is specified by the user of that type. Obviously this means that closed or open, generic types are right out for COM.

The alternatives available are to create a concrete type that wraps the generic type by encapsulation, or to switch to using a non-generic collection type, such as `ArrayList` and be disciplined with the types I use with it.

The down-side with the latter option being that while *I* could have type discipline for data that is returned to the client, there is nothing to force the *client* to follow similar discipline in data that it passes as arguments.
The upside of the former option is that enforces the collection item type and is still as useful to both COM and non-COM clients.